# Считывание меток через метод RFIDWithUHF.readTagFromBuffer не возвращает Tid, а только EPC

Tags: java, android

Внезапно возникла проблема при считывании меток, стандартный метод

```
String[] res = null;
res = mReader.readTagFromBuffer();
```

не возвращает TagId метки, а оставляет в этом районе пустую строку.

В доках :

```
return index 0 means TID infor, index 1 means UII, index 2 means RSSI ( if it is not supported, it will return N/A), null means reading failed.
```

p.s. 
Uii надо конвертировать в EPC и с этим как раз проблемм нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что перед началом инвентаризации надо было установить метод :

```
 mReader.setEPCTIDMode(true);
 mReader.startInventoryTag(0,0,4);
```

где mReader - ваш класс RFIDWithUHF.